# Text format lost after redirecting the output of shell script into a file

Tags: shell

I have an issue with keeping formatted text from my shell script correctly in the output file after redirecting the shell script output into a file.

An example is given as follows:

1. *myshell.sh* content:

   `echo -e "Please print red hello at column 80 \e[80G \e[91m HELLO`
2. Redirecting the output: `*./myshell.sh &> output.txt*`
3. Content of output.txt shown in Notepad++ Editor: 
   `Please print red hello at column 80 ESC[80G ESC[91m HELLO`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? The behaviour you're experiencing is the expected one.

Comment: You would need a plugin that make the escapes visible like coloroued, bold, etc. (maybe even blinking); no idea if such exists for notepad ++ or any editor. You probably get the formatting back by `cat output.txt` in a terminal

Comment: Indeed cat does work. What i try to achieve is storing logfile on the running linux system via shell script with certain text formatting (coloring, bold, and text positioning). And i agree that this may not be in the capability of my text editor like Notepad++. Whad other options do you think do i have?